# How to require a unique value for a field of list item in Firebase without that value being the key?

Tags: validation, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I've been making a little chat application using Angular and Firebase. I've run into some issues with uniqueness though. The app has public channels and I want the names of the channels to be unique. I was using the key to force uniqueness but I was wondering if there was a better way to do this. Here are my current validation rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "public-channels": {
      "$name": {
        ".validate": "!root.child('public-channels').child($name).exists()"  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example of the data

```
{
  "public-channels" : {
    "test1" : {
      "displayName" : "Test1"
    },
    "test2" : {
      "displayName" : "Test2"
    }
  }
}
```

Do you know if there is a solution to this problem where the data can be structured like standard list data that uses a uid as the key and still enforces uniqueness at the database level?

The data format I would like to use is as follows:

```
{
  "public-channels": {
    "SomeUID": {
      "name": "Channel Name" // This value should be unique
    }
  }
}
```

The reason behind wanting this structure is that there are some characters that can't be used in a path to a value (".", "#", "$", "[", or "]") and I would like to allow these characters in the channel names.

Comment: I typically encode the values in the key, so that they don't use illegal characters. Typically URL-encoding works fine iirc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to enforce uniqueness of a specific value within a collection of child nodes. That's precisely why people use keys to enforce uniqueness.

To work around the disallowed characters in a key, I typically encode the values. A simple URL encoding might be enough, although there are probably simpler schemes that work equally well.

Comment: I chose to go with Base64 encoding since encodeUriComponent does not encode the '.' and its working great now. Thanks!